# Uniqueness in sets

Tags: java

If I take for example a `HashSet<E>`, and add objects to it, how does it check if the object's already there?

I have the following simple setup:

```
private class MyObject {
    String text;

    public MyObject(String text) {
        this.text = text;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (o != null && o instanceof MyObject) {
            return ((MyObject) o).text.equals(text);
        }

        return false;
    }

}
```

In my project I have many objects like this, but all initialized separately. I want to filter the doubles, by adding all to a `Set`, like this:

```
MyObject m1 = new MyObject("1");
MyObject m2 = new MyObject("1");
MyObject m3 = new MyObject("2");

System.out.println(m1.equals(m2)); //expected: true, result: true
System.out.println(m1.equals(m3)); //expected: false, result: false

Set<MyObject> myObjects = new HashSet<MyObject>();
myObjects.add(m1);
myObjects.add(m2);
myObjects.add(m3);

System.out.println(myObjects.size()); //expected: 2, result: 3

Set<String> stringList = new HashSet<String>();
stringList.add("1");
stringList.add("1");
stringList.add("2");
System.out.println(stringList.size()); //expected: 2, result: 2
```

How can I make it so that my `myObjects` set does not contain these doubles? So `m1` and `m2` are different instances, but have the same content so I only need `m1`.

**Edit**
Based on Mathias Schwarz's answer I've implemented the `hashCode()` function as follows:

```
@Override
        public int hashCode() {
            return text.hashCode();
        }
```

But how would I implement this method if I have a more complex class with multiple fields?

Comment: for two objects o1, o2, if o1.equals(o2), then they have to return the same hashCode, and your class MyObject does not ensure it. You have to implement the methode hashCode in your class

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`HashSet` determines whether two object are identical on the results of invoking `equals` and `hashCode` on the object. You must implement `hashCode` if you implement `equals`. If they are inconsistent, `HashSet` will not behave correctly... 
So the important thing is how those two methods are implemented on `MyObject` (which btw is really a class...).

Comment: Ah that makes sense, and it works. I've implemented the `hashCode()` function to return `text.hashCode()`. But how would I implement this method if I have multiple fields in the `MyObject` class?

Comment: @Niek you must implement it so that it conforms to the hash code contract; see for example DVK's answer on [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2707541/why-should-i-override-hashcode-when-i-override-equals-method?rq=1).

Comment: if `o1.equals(o2)` then it must be the case that `o1.hashCode() == o2.hashCode()` (but not necessarily the other way around...

Answer (score 2):

If your using eclipse then **Right Click --> Source --> Generate hashCode and Equals** .If you what to know more about hash code and equals read [this portion](http://books.google.co.in/books?id=ka2VUBqHiWkC&pg=PA45&lpg=PA45&dq=effective%20java%20hashcode%20equals&source=bl&ots=yYHfIip5S0&sig=kvzj9N56FXje8K9e_oqMIBkBOWc&hl=en&sa=X&ei=8QR4UM2nB8mUrgf-14GICg&ved=0CEsQ6AEwBA#v=onepage&q=effective%20java%20hashcode%20equals&f=false) from [Effective Java](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321356683) .

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Mathias Schwarz.

For further information: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode() and http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals(java.lang.Object)

Answer (score 0):

add the following to your class MyObject

```
public String hashCode() {
  return text.hashCode();
}
```

(I suppose that text is not null. If it may be null, you'd have to take that into acccoutn and void a NPE)