# .contains() operator not working for ArrayList with object

Tags: java, arraylist

I am using the following code:

```
final UnassignedSubjectData selsub = (UnassignedSubjectData) spinSelectSubject
            .getSelectedItem();
ArrayList<UnassignedSubjectData> selectedSubjectList = null;
    if (selsubdata != null) {
        selectedSubjectList = new ArrayList<UnassignedSubjectData>(
                Arrays.asList(selsubdata));
        Log.d(LOGTAG, "Check " + selsub.toString());
        Log.d(LOGTAG, "Check " + selectedSubjectList.toString());
        Log.d(LOGTAG, "Result for if "
                + Arrays.asList(selsubdata).contains(Arrays.asList(selsub)));
if (selectedSubjectList.contains(Arrays.asList(selsub))) {
            CustomToast.showCustomToast(this,
                    "Subject already present in list");
            Log.d(LOGTAG,
                    "IN IF after TOAST " + selectedSubjectList.toString());
            return;
        }
        else
            Log.d(LOGTAG, "Showing subject not in list");
    }
```

The `selsub` is an object of `UnassignedSubjectData`.

I get the following in the for one of the conditions in LogCat:

```
Check History
Check [History, Science, Science, History]
Result for if false
Showing subject not in list
```

That means even when the object is present in the `ArrayList` the `.contains()` operator is not working properly.
Please help me find a solution for this.

Comment: Have you implemented `equals` and `hashCode` for your `UnassignedSubjectData` class? And why are you putting a list of one element inside the other list?

Comment: @NilsH i put one element inside other list, just so because the .contains() with one element was not working... however trying this also didnt work

Comment: Probably because you have not implemented `equals` and `hashCode`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, as @LuiggiMendoza points out, the call

```
Arrays.asList(selsubdata).contains(Arrays.asList(selsub))
```

will never return true here, since you want to look for an element, not a sublist. Change this to:

```
Arrays.asList(selsubdata).contains(selsub)
```

Second, [`List#contains()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#contains%28java.lang.Object%29) uses the `equals()` method of the list elements for comparison. The default `equals()` inherited from `Object` compares references, which will not work as you want.

For `contains()` to work properly for your object, you need to implement `equals()` (and `hashCode()`) for `UnassignedSubjectData`.

`hashCode()` is not actually needed for comparison, but it should always be implemented together with `equals()`.

Comment: If you read the code carefully, OP's trying to verify if `Arrays.asList(selsubdata)` contains `Arrays.asList(selsub)`. After fixing this, your answer is valid.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza ya u r right... i put one element inside other list with asList, just so because the .contains() with one element was not working... however trying this also didnt work

Comment: @7bluephoenix the problem is that you're verifying if your list `contains` a `List<UnassignedSubjectData>` instance, which will always give you `false`. Please read the JavaDoc of [`List#contains`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#contains(java.lang.Object))

Comment: @Keppil where and how do i implement the two functions that you have suggested in your answer?

Comment: @Keppil & LuiggiMendoza .... thanks for the help... it worked...
actually i did not even have to change the overridden hashCode() function....

Comment: @7bluephoenix: You are very welcome. Maybe you didn't need to override `hashCode()` now, but you really should. [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2707554/1343161) is an explanation why.

Answer (score 1):

Ovevride `equals()` and `hashcode()` for the properties on the basis of which you want to define equality. Then, `contains()` will work for those properties.