# Why it is necessary to override equals when I am overriding hashcode and getting values from hashmap

Tags: java, hashmap, equals, hashcode

```
public class DemoHashSet {
private String name;
private String dob;
private String gender;

public DemoHashSet(String name, String dob, String gender) {
    super();
    this.name = name;
    this.dob = dob;
    this.gender = gender;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public String getDob() {
    return dob;
}

public String getGender() {
    return gender;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return name+" "+dob+" "+gender;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    return this.name.equals(((DemoHashSet)o).getName());
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    int code = this.name.hashCode() + this.dob.hashCode() + gender.hashCode();
    System.out.println("Hash Code: "+code);
    return code;
}

public static void main(String args[]) throws ParseException {

    Map<DemoHashSet, String> hmap = new HashMap<DemoHashSet, String>();

    DemoHashSet obj1 = new DemoHashSet("key1", "121990", "male");
    DemoHashSet obj2 = new DemoHashSet("key2", "122990", "male");
    DemoHashSet obj3 = new DemoHashSet("key3", "123990", "male");
    DemoHashSet obj4 = new DemoHashSet("key4", "124990", "male");
    DemoHashSet obj5 = new DemoHashSet("key5", "125990", "male");

    hmap.put(obj1, "value1");
    hmap.put(obj2, "value2");
    hmap.put(obj3, "value3");
    hmap.put(obj4, "value4");
    hmap.put(obj5, "value5");

    System.out.println("Get values: ");
    System.out.println(hmap.get(new DemoHashSet("key1", "121990", "male")));
    System.out.println(hmap.get(new DemoHashSet("key2", "122990", "male")));
}
}
```

> In this code I am overriding hashcode() and equals() function

when I run this code i get following output:

```
Hash Code: 1457153183
Hash Code: 1457182975
Hash Code: 1457212767
Hash Code: 1457242559
Hash Code: 1457272351
Get values: 
Hash Code: 1457153183
value1
Hash Code: 1457182975
value2
```

> when I override only hashCode() function and comment equlas() method I get following output:

```
Hash Code: 1457153183
Hash Code: 1457182975
Hash Code: 1457212767
Hash Code: 1457242559
Hash Code: 1457272351
Get values: 
Hash Code: 1457153183
null
Hash Code: 1457182975
null
```

> Need explanation for this behaviour as the hash code computed in both scenarios is same but it gives **null** in 2nd case.

Comment: There are points to considered for equals and hashCode. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27581/what-issues-should-be-considered-when-overriding-equals-and-hashcode-in-java?rq=1

Comment: Also this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/371328/why-is-it-important-to-override-gethashcode-when-equals-method-is-overridden?rq=1

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2265503/why-do-i-need-to-override-the-equals-and-hashcode-methods-in-java?rq=1 , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2707541/why-should-i-override-hashcode-when-i-override-equals-method?rq=1

Comment: This is *not* a duplicate of the "GetHashCode" question because this is Java and that is C#. While similar, they are for *different* environments. (There are plenty of Java-specific duplicates.)

Comment: Who says you have to override `equals()` if you override the hashcode?  I think the _reverse_ is true: You need to override the hashcode if you override `equals()`.

Comment: Consider [What issues should be considered when overriding equals and hashCode in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27581/what-issues-should-be-considered-when-overriding-equals-and-hashcode-in-java/27609#27609)

Comment: Conceptually, any two objects which are equal should generate the same hashcode...

Answer (score 2):

**Need explanation for this behavior**
This is the exact expected behavior i should expect. why?
There is one thing about hascode and that is you can't give 100% assurance of uniqueness for unique object. That means in some cases
different object can have similar hascode.

And HashMap implementation kept that in mind. so when you pass a key they always compare the `hascode` and then check equality (reference check then the `equals()` method ). if nothing found return `null`.  you can check the source code:

```
if (e.hash == hash &&
            ((k = e.key) == key || (key != null && key.equals(k))))
```

This code block says:

- `hash` (hascode) need to be same for both given key and entry key

**AND**

- given key and entry key need to be same object (same reference ) **OR** they need to be equal by the `equals()` method

In you case when you comment the equals method the default implementation of equals() method form the super class is used, which actually check the reference equality  only I guess. so

```
DemoHashSet obj1 = new DemoHashSet("key1", "121990", "male");
```

and later

```
 new DemoHashSet("key1", "121990", "male") //ins hmap.get()
```

doesn't refer to the same object so `equals()` return false  and `get()` return `null` as no match found for the key.
When your `equals()` method exist according to  your implementation you are telling  those object are equal as they have same name.

**hashcode cannot assure and  is not Equality.**

Answer (score 2):

> Need explanation for this behaviour as the hash code computed in both
>   scenarios is same but it gives null in 2nd case.

It all related to how hashmap's `get` methods works internally. When you call `get` method of a hashmap for a `specified key`, Internally this `key's hashcode` method gets called to calculate `bucket location`. Once it gets bucket location, it calls `equals` method of specified key to compare with existing objects inside that bucket (actually class Entry objects) and if any object is equal to specified object according to `equals` method, it returns that object.

> case 1 : I am overriding hashcode() and equals() methods

`hmap.get(new DemoHashSet("key1", "121990", "male"))
hmap.get(new DemoHashSet("key2", "122990", "male"))`

according to your equals method implementation, two DemoHashSet objects are equal if they have same name. Thats why you are getting results in this case.

> case 2 : I override only hashCode() function and comment equlas() method

`hmap.get(new DemoHashSet("key1", "121990", "male"))
hmap.get(new DemoHashSet("key2", "122990", "male"))`

In this case, no custom equals method implementation available, so it will take default implementation and according to default implementation - two objects are same if and only if their references are same. So `new DemoHashSet("key1", "121990", "male")` and `new DemoHashSet("key1", "121990", "male")` are not same even they are carrying same values. So hashmap is not getting those objects in that bucket. That's why you are getting null.

For more info: http://javarevisited.blogspot.in/2011/02/how-hashmap-works-in-java.html

Answer (score 1):

You are using a `HashMap`.  Internally, `HashMap`'s have a number of buckets, each of which has a list of the items you are storing.

Whenever you call `HashMap.get()`, the `HashMap` will call `DemoHashSet.hashCode()` and use the key argument, possibly with the modulus (`%`) operator, to figure out which bucket to look in.

Then, it will search through this list using the `DemoHashSet.equals()` method to see if it can match the key argument.  If it `equals()` ever returns `true`, then the value will be returned, otherwise `null`.

From the documentation for [Object.equals()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals(java.lang.Object)):

> Note that it is generally necessary to override the hashCode method
>   whenever this method is overridden, so as to maintain the general
>   contract for the hashCode method, which states that equal objects must
>   have equal hash codes.

Answer (score 0):

> hadCode() function has meant for storing the object in a specific segment/bucket by deriving the key of object to specific segment/bucket. To understand the purpose of this method, you need to know how HashTable or HashMap works internally. Wikipedia is the best source to understand about it.
>
> equals() function has meant for checking the existence of particular Object in the collection object.
>
> If two objects are equal, the hasCode will be same but converse is not true. Two different objects can have same hashCode